# is it possible to join a dicord channel via someones discord ID

Tags: python, discord

i wanna make a bot that joins whatever vc someone is in and then play an audio, im strugglin g to find a way to make the bot join though

im using discord.py

```
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel #gets channel name
        voice  = await channel.connect() #joins channel
        source = FFmpegPCMAudio('source.wav')
        player = voice.play(source)
        channel.connect() #joins authors channel
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ctx.author.voice is None:
  return await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, You have to be connected to a voice channel.")

channel = ctx.author.voice.channel

if ctx.voice_client is None: # if bot is not connected to a voice channel, connecting to a voice channel
    await channel.connect()
else: # else, just moving to ctx author voice channel
    await ctx.voice_client.move_to(channel)
```